# VS2017 Entity Framework 6 - where are my tables?

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have an existing database in SQL Server so I created a new C# ASP.NET MVC project and updated `web.config` to point to the existing database (which actually only held the current AspNetXxxx set of tables).

I created some model classes:

```
public class Project
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public string ProjectType { get; set; }
    public DateTime created { get; set; }
}

public class Portfolio
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PortfolioName { get; set; }
    public List<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}

public class PortfolioContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Portfolio> Portfolios { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
            .Property(p => p.Id)
            .HasColumnName("ProjId");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Portfolio>()
            .Property(p => p.Id)
            .HasColumnName("PortId");
    }
}
```

I then used the Package Manager Console to: `Enable-Migrations` (using my new `ContextType` of `PortfolioContext`), `Add-Migration`, and then `Update-Database`.

I also created the relevant `PortfolioController` and associated views (using the existing context in the wizard).

The existing database hasn't been updated with the new tables - but when I run the application, it works fine and after closing down the site and re-opening, it still has the Portfolios that I created so it is obviously storing the details somewhere... but where are they?

Looking at the Migration record, it has the following code:

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Portfolios",
            c => new
                {
                    PortfolioId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    PortfolioName = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.PortfolioId);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Projects",
            c => new
                {
                    ProjectId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    ProjectName = c.String(),
                    ProjectType = c.String(),
                    created = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    Portfolio_Id = c.Int(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.ProjectId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Portfolios", t => t.Portfolio_Id)
            .Index(t => t.Portfolio_Id);

    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Projects", "Portfolio_Id", "dbo.Portfolios");
        DropIndex("dbo.Projects", new[] { "Portfolio_Id" });
        DropTable("dbo.Projects");
        DropTable("dbo.Portfolios");
    }
```

... so it seems the tables have been setup correctly with owner "dbo"... I just don't know where...

Comment: Can you show the web.config? It seems that your database could not be found, and it created a local database.

Comment: Go to PMC and execute `Get-Migrations -verbose`. Then look at the output line starting with `Target database is: `

Answer (score 0):

Thanks both (@Bob Lokerse & @Ivan Stoev) for your responses.
Whilst not directly answering, it did enable me to investigate further and fix.
Further details which helped: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592674.aspx

EF was indeed creating it's own DB on the (localdb) and "Get-Migrations -verbose" allowed me to find where.
What I needed was to change the base of the Context model to point to a specific/existing DB (as below) - and this worked - the tables were created in the existing DB alongside my other tables (where "DefaultConnection" is the web.config connection string where my existing DB is):

```
public class PortfolioContext : DbContext
{
    public PortfolioContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Portfolio> Portfolios { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
            .Property(p => p.Id)
            .HasColumnName("ProjId");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Portfolio>()
            .Property(p => p.Id)
            .HasColumnName("PortId");
    }
}
```